# get array content in php

Tags: php, arrays

I want to get data from an array using PHP loop like FOR or FOREACH.
when I print the content of the array using var_dump it looks like this:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(6) "query1"
    ["fql_result_set"]=>
    array(13) {
      [0]=>
      array(3) {
        ["aid"]=>
        string(19) "2944783819003364347"
        ["name"]=>
        string(16) "Profile Pictures"
        ["photo_count"]=>
        string(2) "37"
      }
      [1]=>
      array(3) {
        ["aid"]=>
        string(19) "2944783820076875780"
        ["name"]=>
        string(7) "only me"
        ["photo_count"]=>
        string(1) "2"
      }
      [2]=>
      array(3) {
        ["aid"]=>
        string(19) "2944783819003517141"
        ["name"]=>
        string(35) "Ways To Tie Your Shoelaces. Nice :)"
        ["photo_count"]=>
        string(1) "8"
      }
      [3]=>
      array(3) {
        ["aid"]=>
        string(19) "2944783819003490957"
        ["name"]=>
        string(12) "Cover Photos"
        ["photo_count"]=>
        string(2) "12"
      }
      [4]=>
      array(3) {
        ["aid"]=>
        string(19) "2944783819003481818"
        ["name"]=>
        string(14) "Mobile Uploads"
        ["photo_count"]=>
        string(2) "55"
      }
    }
  }
```

what should I do to `get: ["aid"] , ["name" ] and ["photo_count"]?`

Comment: `foreach($array as $Google){ // USE GOOGLE }`

Answer (score 1):

like this

```
foreach ($array[0]['fql_result_set'] as $record) {
    echo "{$record['aid']}, {$record['name']}";
}
```

Comment: Why not just `echo $record['aid'], $record['name'];`

Comment: because echo need 1 argument which is string, this gives you fatal error.

Comment: Did you actually check it or you just *assume* that it will give you an error? http://php.net/echo

Comment: it doesn't matter, does it ?